# In Enyo js, Difference between waterfall and waterfalldown

Tags: javascript, enyo

In **enyo.js**, what is the difference between waterfall and waterfalldown event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`waterfall` will send the event starting with the component where you call it (i.e., this.waterfall(...) will send the event to whatever this is) and `waterfallDown` skips that level and sends to all the components it contains.

There are also `bubble` and `bubbleUp` which behave similarly but in the opposite direction.